# How to replace double comma with a single comma in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I convert this `2016-01-04` into this `2016-01-04` in JavaScript?

I have a dataset in an array with dates like this:

```
["x", "2016-01-04", "2016-01-05", "2016-01-06", "2016-01-07", "2016-01-08", "2016-01-09"]
```

And I want to covert them to:

```
['x', '2016-01-04', '2016-01-05', '2016-01-06', '2016-01-07', '2016-01-08', '2016-01-09']
```

I have tried `.replace(/"/g, "'")`

but I get an error `forcastDate_ordered.replace is not a function`

Comment: use .replace("\"","\'")

Comment: the quotation mark is part of the string???

Comment: @HussainAlmomen updated my question

Comment: That just looks like an array of normal strings, can we see more code?

Comment: what is the purpose of changing them may i ask?

Comment: Is it me, or is the "to" version the same as the "from" ?

Comment: Short answer: you can't.   They're not quotes in a string, they *are* strings already. This is assuming your "array" is actually something like:  `var arr = ["x","y"];`.  Hard to tell from the question.

Comment: There is really no meaning in your expected behaviour. The opposite though could have some meaning, getting valid JSON notation object. And your two posted examles are exactly the same, you should put more effort while posting question...

Comment: @A.Wolff The problem is that with double quotes my chart dows not render while with single quote it renders perfectly see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yrzxj3x2/1/

Comment: In the fiddle, it renders the same way with single and double quotes

Answer (score 0):

```
    var endString = startString.replace(/"/g, "'");

Example:

    var startString = 'I hate "double" quotes';
    var endString = startString .replace(/"/g, "'");
    endString = I hate 'double' quotes
or

doubleQuotesReplacer = (startString)  => startString .replace(/"/g, "'");
```

Comment: Will it be the same when The string is in an array like ["I hate double quotes", "this is another quote"]

Comment: he has an array it wont work like that. Even if you convert the array toString it will get rid of the quotes

Answer (score 0):

See [Special Characters (JavaScript) from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yfce773(v=vs.94).aspx)

Characters like the speech mark " and single quotation mark ' can be escaped with a backslash \ - this is helpful when they are in strings using speech marks or quotation marks around them.

And to replace the characters, use [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

So the final answer as others have stated is

```
string s = "\"2016-01-04\"";
return s.replace("\"", "'");
```

(The single quote is not escaped because the string is surrounded by speech marks " - so it doesn't need it)

UPDATE: your question is changed to involve arrays

In which case, you need [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
array.map(s => s.replace("\"", "'"));
```